# How do you get ripple effect to extend past view bounds?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

The touch ripple effect here expands past its bounds. How is this done?

[image]

EDIT: I am okay with this working on 5.0+ only.

Comment: How did you managed to work that way on 5.0+?

Comment: this is a screenshot from the Google Keep app. I am wondering how to get the ripple effect to not extend below, but extend to the left|top|right - like the google keep app.

Answer (score 11):

I've read from a few places that:

> If you want to apply the standard ripple effect on Android 5.0: API 21
>   or more, which should not be limited to your view (unbounded ripple),
>   just apply to your View background :

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: That does work to extend past view bounds, but to match what I see in the picture, the ripple needs to be limited to the "Add a quick note" area.

Comment: How does it work? Is it possible to customize it? Maybe have a different color and size, like on the Dialer app ?

Answer (score 3):

I have tested it, what is happening here is that the ripple is not on the buttons, but on the background object. So the ripple is not actually extending past the buttons bounds here, but rather extending to the bounds of the background wrapper card object.

To replicate what you see in the picture,
 1. Make a new layout. I would use either a relative layout or linearlayout
 2.  Add the upper EditText ("Add a quick note"), and then and the four lower buttons, all with clear backgrounds, but with gray borders like above.
 3. Set your ripple animation on the background of the layout you put the buttons in, and be sure to set `android:clickable="true"`on your layout!

That gave me the same effect as your picture.

Comment: But this will not extend the ripple outside of "Add quick note". Thats the limitation.

Comment: @AliKazi, Correct, but I think that is what he was asking for. To extend even further past the "Add a quick note", one could just instead apply the ripple further up the view hierarchy, provided they are happy with clear backgrounds.

Comment: For me, I have a TabLayout for bottom tabs and it doesnt show ripple effect even if I set `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`. I am making something new now, and if it works I wonder why the solution I have in mind has not been suggested as an answer in any SO questions related to this so far.

Answer (score 0):

doc already mentioned it

```
//An unbounded red ripple. 
<ripple android:color="#ffff0000" />
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html